# How to add metadata to streaming client call [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node

How to add metadata to streaming client call [Nodejs]

```
let meta = new grpc.Metadata();
meta.add('authorization', 'token');

let call = client.StreamCall();
call.write(data);
call.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass the metadata as an (optional) argument when creating the call. See the [example code in our interop app](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/49298d20fa330c0acbd04611229171359e5adcec/test/interop/interop_client.js#L313) and the API documentation [here](https://grpc.io/grpc/node/grpc.Client.html#makeClientStreamRequest__anchor).